# Mysql / MariaDB Limit Rows Queried (not limit rows returned)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Hypothetically, let's assume that:

- I have a database of all people that have lived on earth - 113 billion rows. (id, birth_date, first_name, last_name, etc..)
- Each day exactly 400,000 people are born and added to the end of the database.

I would like to quickly find everybody with the last name of "Smith" that was born yesterday.

Instead of querying 113 billion records by date and name (slow), I would like to ONLY search the last 400,000 records by name (fast). Is there a way to do that?

Currently, I have two databases, new and archive, and I can search the new database quickly. When records get old they move from new to archive. It works but there is probably a better way to do it that I can't figure out by searching.

Comment: What you are missing are **indexes.** You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), and the [video of me giving the presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

Comment: You can also look into using database partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these would be even faster than searching 400K rows:

```
INDEX(last_name, birthday)

INDEX(birthday, last_name)
```

The former is likely to be more useful because it would allow you to quickly find "all Smiths born in the last week".